# Execute a command in a Kubernetes pod automatically without overriding entrypoint, which an infinite loop to keep pod alive

Tags: kubernetes

Execute a command in a Kubernetes pod after entrypoint, which an infinite loop to keep pod alive.

Constrains

1. I cant modify the entrypoint file.
2. I dont want to create a new image where original image is base and I  use RUN

Exploration done.

1. post start life cycle. But the problem with this is the the Kubernetes documentation itself says that there is no guarantee that this will start after init. so i cant rely on this to start the command after entrypoint